# python multiprocessing efficiency

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

timer function for calculate the cost time between multi_core_1 and multi_core_2

## multi_core_1

```
results = p.map_async(deal, urls)
```

## multi_core_2

```
for url in urls:
    results = p.map_async(deal, url)
```

## Code

````
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import time
import logging
from functools import wraps
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool, Queue, Manager, freeze_support
import requests

urls = [
    'http://www.baidu.com',
    'http://home.baidu.com/',
    ```
    another 100 urls
]


def timer(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t = time.time()
        back = func(*args, **kwargs)
        logging.warn('%s cost %s' % (func.__name__, (time.time()-t)))
        return back
    return wrapper


def deal(url):
    return requests.get(url).status_code


@timer
def multi_core_1():
    freeze_support()
    p = Pool(8)
    results = p.map_async(deal, urls)
    p.close()
    p.join()


@timer
def multi_core_2():
    freeze_support()
    p = Pool(8)
    for url in urls:
        results = p.map_async(deal, url)
    p.close()
    p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multi_core_1()
    multi_core_2()
````

## result

```
> python test.py
WARNING:root:multi_core_1 cost 1.3149404525756836
WARNING:root:multi_core_2 cost 0.2142746448516845
```

## Question

So I wonder how multi_core_2() can be faster than multi_core_1()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second function you're using `map_async` wrong.

`map_async` takes a function to apply and an *iterable*.

When you pass a string as an iterable, it treats each character in the string as an element. So for each URL in the list it tries to apply the `deal` function to each character individually ('h', 't', 't', etc). Obviously this fails in the `requests.get` outright, so it immediately fails, doesn't have to load a page and is thus faster; it's broken code that doesn't work, though.

You're also assigning to `results` on each loop iteration, so it'll overwrite itself on each new URL and just contain the error codes for the last URL string.

Before checking for function performance, make sure the function actually works as intended.

Comment: actually, you're right, multi_core_2 doesn't work cause requests fail,    Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Actualy it doesn't faster. It is wrong method to calculate performance, because it depends on IO wait. I guess that `multi_core_2()` faster in your case because DNS were resolved and cached at the `multi_core_1()` execution.